# Luxon substracting one day if JS date is UTC

Tags: javascript, date, luxon

I create a date with Luxon in the following way:

```
const date = DateTime.utc(2000, 6, 23).toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Then I try to convert it to a JS date by doing this:

```
const jsDate = new Date(date)
```

Finally, I convert it back to the 'yyyy-MM-dd' format with

```
const parsedDate = DateTime.fromJSDate(jsDate).toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

But instead of giving me 2000-06-23 it gives me 2000-06-22. Is this a bug on Luxon or I need to do something to get the correct date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I try to convert it to a JS date by doing `const jsDate = new Date(date)`

Uh, why not just [`date.toJSDate()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetojsdate)?

> Instead of giving me 2000-06-23, `DateTime.fromJSDate(jsDate).toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')` gives me 2000-06-22. Is this a bug on Luxon or I need to do something to get the correct date?

According to [its docs](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromjsdate), `fromJSDate` [defaults to creating a `DateTime` instance in the `local` (system) timezone](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/zones?id=system-zone-by-default). If you expect another UTC date back, you need to specify that:

```
DateTime.fromJSDate(jsDate, {zone: 'utc'}).toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
```